# Как сгруппировать массив оъектов по свойству, которое является массивом?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Как быстро сгруппировать массив объектов по свойству, которое является само массивом?

Дан массив

```
[
 { days: [15, 17], title: ‘test1’},
 { days: [15], title: ‘test2’},
 { days: [15], title: ‘test3’},
 { days: [15, 19], title: ‘test4’},
 { days: [15, 19], title: ‘test5’},
]
```

Получить такой массив

```
[
 {days: [15, 19], events: [{title: ‘test4’}, {title: ‘test5} ]]
 {days: [15], events: [{title: ‘test2}, {title: ‘test3’}]
 {days: [15, 17], events: [{title: ‘test1}]]
]
```

Можно через lodash

Comment: точно так же как и по любому другому свойству

Comment: @Grundy Все ж таки дело тут несколько осложняется тем, что `[15, 19] != [15, 19]`, нет?

Comment: @Yaant, подход-то один и тот же, просто нужно функцию сравнения написать, а такие вопрос как проверить на равенство массивы - уже были

Comment: @Grundy подход-то да, но вот конкретно этот момент может оказаться не столь очевидным, и код, прекрасно работающий для примитивных значений, внезапно выдаст не тот результат для массивов (а если еще окажется, что в исходном объекте часть ссылок ссылаются на один и тот же объект, а другая часть - нет, то результат может озадачить вообще очень сильно) :)

Comment: @Yaant, почти уверен что данные из  `json` поэтому проблемы с одинаковыми объектами не будет :)